# A new sheet that is a real-time filtered version of another sheet?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, filter, match

I wonder if the following scenario is possible:

We have a simple sheet in G Sheet (let's call it **Sheet1**) with some columns and one column called `IsProcessed` that can either be 0 or 1.

Is it possible to have another sheet (**Sheet2**) in the same document that is identical to **Sheet1** except that it only contains rows with `IsProcessed = 0`.

Of course, **Sheet2** should be updated in real-time as values in **Sheet1** change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. if column `IsProcessed` is for example `D` use this formula in Sheet2:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:Z; Sheet1!D:D=0)
```

---

### update:

```
={Sheet1!A1:Z1; FILTER(Sheet1!A2:Z; Sheet1!D2:D=0; Sheet1!D2:D<>"")}
```

Comment: Oh, cheers! Let me try and come back!

Comment: Where in **Sheet2** should I apply this filter?

Comment: @disasterkid any cell you wish. preferably A1

Comment: Which column is  `IsProcessed = 0`

Comment: Replace D:D with the column that contain 0's and 1's "IsProcessed" `=FILTER(Sheet1!A:Z; Sheet1![IsProcessed column]=0)`

Comment: @player0 Almost there, but the whole sheet is copied (including rows that have an empty value for `IsProcessed`. Also the header row (column names) is not copied.

Comment: @Osm player0's answer is almost working, I think your missed one small thing, it should be `=FILTER(Sheet1!A:Z; Sheet1![IsProcessed column]:[IsProcessed column]=0)`

Comment: @disasterkid answer updated. use 2nd formula

Comment: Specify `IsProcessed` column in the qustion for future visitors and the answer be seamless